# Downloaded image shows in computer but not in mobiles folder

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am working on an image wallpaper application in android when i download the image from url sometime it shows images on mobile but most of time it does't show but when i connect my mobile to computer its right in the specified folder.
Thanks advance looking forward for answer.

Here is my code to download image.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = null;
        try {

            // set the path where we want to save the file
            // in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
            // sd card.
            File dir = Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            String filename = _imagePaths[FullScreenImage.position]
                    .substring(_imagePaths[FullScreenImage.position]
                            .lastIndexOf("/"));
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, filename);
            Log.i("Local filename:", "" + filename);
            // this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file
            // we created
            fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Bitmap mybitmap = imageLoader.getBitmap(
                    _imagePaths[FullScreenImage.position], 800, 480);
            mybitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutput);
            // close the output stream when done

            // catch some possible errors...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Download Image catch > ", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (fileOutput != null) {
                try {
                    fileOutput.flush();
                    fileOutput.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("Download Image catch > ", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` to notify the system about new media files.

Comment: After writing the file, yes.